# PrestaShop: allow customers to upload PDF, AI and EPS files as product customization

Tags: php, file-upload, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am running Prestashop 1.6.1.7 and I have the following pictureUpload() method that allows users to upload files of their choosing. By default Prestashop allows uploads of GIF, JPG, JPEG or PNG only.

I'm trying to allow users the ability to upload a few more types (pdf, ai and eps specifically)

Here is the pictureUpload() method in the productController override:

```
protected function pictureUpload()
{
    if (!$field_ids = $this->product->getCustomizationFieldIds()) {
        return false;
    }
    $authorized_file_fields = array();
    foreach ($field_ids as $field_id) {
        if ($field_id['type'] == Product::CUSTOMIZE_FILE) {
            $authorized_file_fields[(int)$field_id['id_customization_field']] = 'file'.(int)$field_id['id_customization_field'];
        }
    }
    $indexes = array_flip($authorized_file_fields);
    foreach ($_FILES as $field_name => $file) {
        if (in_array($field_name, $authorized_file_fields) && isset($file['tmp_name']) && !empty($file['tmp_name'])) {
            //$file_name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
            $file_name = $file['name']; // In this

            if ($error = ImageManager::validateUpload($file, (int)Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCT_PICTURE_MAX_SIZE'))) {
                $this->errors[] = $error;
            }

            $product_picture_width = (int)Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCT_PICTURE_WIDTH');
            $product_picture_height = (int)Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCT_PICTURE_HEIGHT');
            $tmp_name = tempnam(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_, 'PS');
            if ($error || (!$tmp_name || !move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $tmp_name))) {
                return false;
            }
            /* Original file */
            if (!ImageManager::resize($tmp_name, _PS_UPLOAD_DIR_.$file_name)) {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred during the image upload process.');
            }
            /* A smaller one */
            elseif (!ImageManager::resize($tmp_name, _PS_UPLOAD_DIR_.$file_name.'_small', $product_picture_width, $product_picture_height)) {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred during the image upload process.');
            } elseif (!chmod(_PS_UPLOAD_DIR_.$file_name, 0777) || !chmod(_PS_UPLOAD_DIR_.$file_name.'_small', 0777)) {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred during the image upload process.');
            } else {
                $this->context->cart->addPictureToProduct($this->product->id, $indexes[$field_name], Product::CUSTOMIZE_FILE, $file_name);
            }
            unlink($tmp_name);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is looking to the ImageManager class, which has this method (that I have updated the error message on):

```
public static function validateUpload($file, $max_file_size = 0, $types = null)
{

    if ((int)$max_file_size > 0 && $file['size'] > (int)$max_file_size) {
        return sprintf(Tools::displayError('Image is too large (%1$d kB). Maximum allowed: %2$d kB'), $file['size'] / 1024, $max_file_size / 1024);
    }
    if (!ImageManager::isRealImage($file['tmp_name'], $file['type']) || !ImageManager::isCorrectImageFileExt($file['name'], $types) || preg_match('/\%00/', $file['name'])) {
        return Tools::displayError('Image format not recognized, allowed formats are: .gif, .jpg, .png, .pdf, .ai, .eps'); //I Updated This - this is the error kicking off when I try to upload AI
    }
    if ($file['error']) {
        return sprintf(Tools::displayError('Error while uploading image; please change your server\'s settings. (Error code: %s)'), $file['error']);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The place where that method fails is pointing to two additional methods posted below. I updated the isRealImage method to try and allow the types I wanted through, but it still fails (and I commented where it fails).

```
public static function isRealImage($filename, $file_mime_type = null, $mime_type_list = null)
{
    // Detect mime content type
    $mime_type = false;
    if (!$mime_type_list) {
        //I UPDATED THIS LIST TO ALLOW FOR OTHER FILETYPES
        $mime_type_list = array('image/gif', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png', 'application/illustrator', 'application/ai', 'application/eps', 'application/x-eps', 'image/eps', 'image/x-eps', 'application/pdf', 'application/acrobat', 'application/x-pdf', 'text/pdf', 'text/x-pdf');
    }

    // Try 4 different methods to determine the mime type

    if (function_exists('getimagesize')) {
        $image_info = @getimagesize($filename);
        //HERE IMAGE_INFO IS SHOWING AS 'FALSE' SO IT GOES NO FURTHER WHEN UPLOADING A .AI FILE
        if ($image_info) {
            $mime_type = $image_info['mime'];
        } else {
            $file_mime_type = false;
        }
    } elseif (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
        $const = defined('FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE') ? FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE : FILEINFO_MIME;
        $finfo = finfo_open($const);
        $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } elseif (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
        $mime_type = mime_content_type($filename);
    } elseif (function_exists('exec')) {
        $mime_type = trim(exec('file -b --mime-type '.escapeshellarg($filename)));
        if (!$mime_type) {
            $mime_type = trim(exec('file --mime '.escapeshellarg($filename)));
        }
        if (!$mime_type) {
            $mime_type = trim(exec('file -bi '.escapeshellarg($filename)));
        }
    }

    if ($file_mime_type && (empty($mime_type) || $mime_type == 'regular file' || $mime_type == 'text/plain')) {
        $mime_type = $file_mime_type;
    }

    // For each allowed MIME type, we are looking for it inside the current MIME type
    foreach ($mime_type_list as $type) {
        if (strstr($mime_type, $type)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I also updated the isCorrectImageFileExt method:

```
public static function isCorrectImageFileExt($filename, $authorized_extensions = null)
{
    // Filter on file extension
    if ($authorized_extensions === null) {
        //ADDED ALLOWED TYPES I WANT
        $authorized_extensions = array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'jpe', 'png', 'pdf', 'ai', 'eps');
    }
    $name_explode = explode('.', $filename);
    if (count($name_explode) >= 2) {
        $current_extension = strtolower($name_explode[count($name_explode) - 1]);
        if (!in_array($current_extension, $authorized_extensions)) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thoughts on this?

Help on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have gone too deep :). This is the `pictureUpload` method of `ProductController` that I've already made, you don't need others overrides. With my override you can upload pdf, ai, cdr and eps, but obviously you can change with your needs.

```
protected function pictureUpload()
{
    if (!$field_ids = $this->product->getCustomizationFieldIds()) {
        return false;
    }
    $authorized_file_fields = array();
    foreach ($field_ids as $field_id) {
        if ($field_id['type'] == Product::CUSTOMIZE_FILE) {
            $authorized_file_fields[(int)$field_id['id_customization_field']] = 'file'.(int)$field_id['id_customization_field'];
        }
    }
    $indexes = array_flip($authorized_file_fields);

    foreach ($_FILES as $field_name => $file) {
        if (in_array($field_name, $authorized_file_fields) && isset($file['tmp_name']) && !empty($file['tmp_name'])) {
            $file_name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

            // Bad check, but rapid
            $extension = substr($file['name'], -3, 3);
            if($extension == 'jpg' OR $extension == 'gif' OR $extension == 'png'){
                if ($error = ImageManager::validateUpload($file, (int)Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCT_PICTURE_MAX_SIZE'))) {
                    $this->errors[] = $error;
                }

                $product_picture_width = (int)Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCT_PICTURE_WIDTH');
                $product_picture_height = (int)Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCT_PICTURE_HEIGHT');
                $tmp_name = tempnam(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_, 'PS');
                if ($error || (!$tmp_name || !move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $tmp_name))) {
                    return false;
                }
                /* Original file */
                if (!ImageManager::resize($tmp_name, _PS_UPLOAD_DIR_.$file_name)) {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred during the image upload process.');
                }
                /* A smaller one */
                elseif (!ImageManager::resize($tmp_name, _PS_UPLOAD_DIR_.$file_name.'_small', $product_picture_width, $product_picture_height)) {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred during the image upload process.');
                } elseif (!chmod(_PS_UPLOAD_DIR_.$file_name, 0777) || !chmod(_PS_UPLOAD_DIR_.$file_name.'_small', 0777)) {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred during the image upload process.');
                } else {
                    $this->context->cart->addPictureToProduct($this->product->id, $indexes[$field_name], Product::CUSTOMIZE_FILE, $file_name);
                }
                unlink($tmp_name);
            } elseif ($extension == 'pdf' OR $extension == '.ai' OR $extension == 'cdr' OR $extension == 'eps') {
                $file_name = $file_name.'.'.str_replace('.', '', $extension);
                if (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], _PS_UPLOAD_DIR_.$file_name)) {
                    return false;
                }
                chmod(_PS_UPLOAD_DIR_.$file_name, 0777);
                $this->context->cart->addPictureToProduct($this->product->id, $indexes[$field_name], Product::CUSTOMIZE_FILE, $file_name);
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('This format is not accepted');
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

After that you have to customize `product.tpl`, the cart summary of your template, and the backoffice order detail :)

Comment: Thanks! It works - additional question: when you said "After that you have to customize product.tpl, the cart summary of your template, and the backoffice order detail" was that just to show the upload? or what was the logic behind updating the rest of that?

Comment: Because the front is coded to display images, when the customer load a pdf or another file that the browser can't display like an image you have the ugly square of 'image not found' :), and if I remember right you should have problem to download the files.

Comment: @sarcom: I assume that this applies only for the front-end, right? Is there a way to allow pdf upload via web service rest api ?

Comment: @el.severo Yes that method is only from front end. If you want to upload pdf from web services I suppose you have to edit some other stuff, at the moment I don't remember the (webservices)methods for the product customization :)

Comment: @sarcom: Yup. It seems the upload of a PDF file via web service is recommended via "virtual product" creation and then attach it. It's a workaround. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you do not want to hack your PrestaShop installation, which is not recommended if you want to be able to upgrade PretaShop safely, is to develop or use an existing module.

This module on the PrestaShop marketplace is probably what you are looking for:
https://addons.prestashop.com/en/front-office-features-prestashop-modules/88383-upload-any-file-type-in-product-customization.html