# Type file Prestashop customizationFields

Tags: php, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I would like to see replace the file type to upload to prestashop and replace it with PDFs instead of PNG, JPG, ... with the `customizationFieldsField`.

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I guess this question (and answer) should help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925327/prestashop-allow-customers-to-upload-pdf-ai-and-eps-files-as-product-customiza/39930492#39930492

Comment: Thank its work but 
How can I do to add a PDF pictogram when I add a PDF and there is a bug I have an error message when I add an image now while it is adding ...

Comment: What do you mean for pdf pictogram?

Comment: Add a picto by default pdf example https://www.google.fr/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwimn5ucmOXSAhWJ7RQKHbUwAl0QjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mehach-magazine.com%2F9983201%2Fmodifier-un-pdf-cest-possible-aujourdhui.html&psig=AFQjCNHz7pGW5gQskd2RXciiKg1LmEa63Q&ust=1490102953517008

Comment: I suggest to you to make another question, sorry but I don't understand french ^^"