# Allowing PDF upload in product customization Prestashop 1.6: how to delete the uploaded file

Tags: file-upload, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925327/prestashop-allow-customers-to-upload-pdf-ai-and-eps-files-as-product-customiza/39930492#39930492?newreg=6973279708904b65845343b62d3e335a)  and I'm trying to customize product.tpl

I've added this code to have a pdf icon when the user upload a pdf file:

```
{if isset($pictures.$key)}
{if strpos($pictures.$key, '.pdf') !== false}<br>
<div class="customizationUploadBrowse">
<img src="https://example.com/img/pdf80.png"/>
<a href="{$link->getProductDeletePictureLink($product, $field.id_customization_field)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Delete'}" >
<img src="{$img_dir}icon/delete.gif" alt="{l s='Delete'}" class="customization_delete_icon" width="13" height="13" /></a>
</div>
{else}
<div class="customizationUploadBrowse">
<img src="{$pic_dir}{$pictures.$key}" alt="" style="max-width:100px; max-height: 100px;"/>
<a href="{$link->getProductDeletePictureLink($product, $field.id_customization_field)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Delete'}" >
<img src="{$img_dir}icon/delete.gif" alt="{l s='Delete'}" class="customization_delete_icon" width="13" height="13" />
</a>
</div>
{/if}
{/if}                                           </div>
                                            {/if}{/if}
```

If I try to delete the pdf files, I get an error message even if the file is beeing deleted.

No problems with jpg and png instead.

How can I get the pdf (and, most likely .ai will be added too) to be deleted as well?
Is there a way to upload the files without clicking on "save" button?